# Figuring out this date format

Tags: c#, datetime, binary, instagram, type-conversion

I'm trying to figure out the format of few dates that are available in numeric format. I need to convert them to exact dates. I have a sample dates that I was trying to convert:

```
1443506173.0  >>  Sep 29, 2015
1443505895.0  >>  Sep 29, 2015
1441805416.0  >>  Sep 09, 2015
1438174556.0  >>  Jul 29, 2015
1436476814.0  >>  Jul 10, 2015
1414994162.0  >>  Nov 03, 2014
1413294207.0  >>  Oct 14, 2014
```

By looking at the first two entries, I can see that the numbers are changing but both are representing the same dates. Means there must be time embedded into this date format. Currently I'm concerned with extracting only date, I dont need to extract time at the moment. Would be great if it was simple enough to extract time as well.

Can anyone help figure this out? In case you're wondering, I got these dates from Instagram posts feed. Using WebClient I downloaded an Instagram photo's URL. This date format is there in the scripts section. If I'm able to decode this date format, I would know what the date (and time) of the photo post was at Instagram.

Thanks in advance. I'm using C# to perform this conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instagram uses the [Unix Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for its format (the number of seconds since 1st January 1970).

One method of converting this to a DateTime object would be:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(yourUnixTimestampValue).ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I came way too close. I was adding days instead of seconds to 1970 date.

Answer (score 1):

This is a UNIX Timestamp

```
void Main()
{
    var timestamps = new[]{
        new {stamp = 1443506173.0, datetime = new DateTime(2015, 9, 29)},
        new {stamp = 1443505895.0, datetime = new DateTime(2015, 9, 29)},
        new {stamp = 1413294207.0, datetime = new DateTime(2014, 10, 14)}
    };

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    foreach (var i in timestamps)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}, Converted: {1}", i, new DateTime(1970, 1,1).AddSeconds(i.stamp).ToLongDateString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Item: { stamp = 1443506173, datetime = 09/29/2015 00:00:00 }, Converted: Tuesday, 29 September 2015
Item: { stamp = 1443505895, datetime = 09/29/2015 00:00:00 }, Converted: Tuesday, 29 September 2015
Item: { stamp = 1413294207, datetime = 10/14/2014 00:00:00 }, Converted: Tuesday, 14 October 2014
```